# Disallow space character for username text field for web and mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

I am using this code to disallow space while user is typing and it is working on web:

```
$("#user_name").on("keydown",function(e){
return e.which !==32;
});
```

But it does not work if form is opened on a mobile device browser.How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var check= document.getElementById('user_name').value.contains(' ');
if(check){
//---//
}
else{
//--//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("#user_name").on("keydown",function(e){
$(this).val(function(i,oldVal){ return oldVal.replace(/\s/g,''); }); 
return e.which !==32;
});
```

Tested on Web(Firefox and Chrome) and Mobile(Android and safari).